# Javascript print to file sequentially

Tags: javascript, node.js, file, promise, async-await

Somehow I cannot wrap my head around this problem.

The function `runOneCombination` below is executed for thousands of files and I would like to extract some information, do some calculations and then print them to a file that I keep appending to.

I don't think the other code of this project is needed, but if it is I can share it.

The problem is indicated in the code below. My expectation is that for each iteration of `Promise.all(res.dailyData.map( async (dailyDataRow,index,arr) => {` the three statements are executed in order and the `fs.writeSync(out,'\r\n');` is executed. Unfortunately, this is not what happens. The output contains all output of `writeDaily(out,dailyDataRow)` appended without line breaks in between, but followed by one. Then comes everything contained in `featureRow[0]` (separated by line breaks) then what is in `featureRow[1]` and `featureRow[2]` (without line breaks again).
My expectation was:

```
dailyDataRow,featureRow[0],featureRow[1],featureRow[2],\r\n
```

Previously, this worked, but without append to file so I could only handle one pair of files as input.

```
function runOneCombination(dailyFile,simFile) {
    return new Promise(async function(resolve, reject) {
        let res = await process(dailyFile,simFile);
        var wh = true;
        if(await fs.existsSync(outFilePath))
            wh = false;
        var out = fs.openSync(outFilePath,'a');            
       // out.once('open', async function(fd) {
            //Write Headers   
            if(wh) {
                await writeHeaders(out);
            }
            await Promise.all(res.dailyData.map( async (dailyDataRow,index,arr) => {
                if(index > 1) { 
                    let samples = await getFeatures(dailyDataRow,res.cdData);
                    await samples.forEach(async (featureRow)=>{
                        //console.log(dailyDataRow,featureRow[0],featureRow[1],featureRow[2]);
                        if(!featureRow) 
                            console.log("fail:",featureRow);
                        else { 
//Problem is in the following lines:
                            writeDaily(out,dailyDataRow).then(async(val)=>{
                                writeFeatures(out,featureRow[0]).then(async(val)=>{
                                    writeFeatures(out,featureRow[1]).then(async(val)=>{
                                        writeFeatures(out,featureRow[2]);
                                    });
                                });
                            });
                        }
                    });
                    fs.writeSync(out,'\r\n');
                }

            })).then((val)=>{
                //out.end(); //close the writing stream 
                resolve('success');
            });
       // });  
    });
}
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Why are you even using `then` when you have `await`? You need to stop using `then` and use only `async` functions and `await`.

You never need the Promise constructor unless you are wrapping something that takes a callback.

Your issue is definitely that `samples.forEach` should be:

```
for(featureRow of samples) { }
```

doing that in an async function will fix the issue of ordering. As each iteration will complete before the next.

I do not feel like fixing your code to use only await. But here it is anyway:

```
async function runOneCombination(dailyFile, simFile) {
  let res = await process(dailyFile, simFile);

  let wh = await fs.exists(outFilePath)
  let out = await fs.open(outFilePath, 'a');

  //Write Headers
  if (wh) {
    await writeHeaders(out);
  }

  for (dailyDataRow of res.dailyData.slice(1)) {
    let samples = await getFeatures(dailyDataRow, res.cdData);
    for (featureRow of samples) {
      if (!featureRow) {
        console.log("fail:", featureRow);
        continue;
      }
      //Problem is in the following lines:
      await writeDaily(out, dailyDataRow);
      for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        await writeFeatures(out, featureRow[i])
      }
      await fs.write(out, '\r\n');
    }
  }  
}
```

Looks like it could work but it needs some testing.